Verb+adjective combinations
What are more examples of verb+adjective combinations like “Dress warm; Drive safe; Act calm; Eat healthy” (to give advice, maybe?) Any grammar rules here as we normally use adverbs after verbs?

Go slow, shout loud, drill deep, eat noisy, sleep bad - these, and your two are a few examples of adjectives after action verbs. The 'grammar rule', if you want one, is 'don't do it'. However, as the naughty boy said, rules are made to be broken, and this one is broken by people wishing to make snappy slogans, and of course in casual or informal speech.

Don't pay attention to the dv on my answer. This is a fully formed form in English. It is a passive construction: past participle + adjective.

There are verbs that licences Predicative Complements, which are sometimes realized by Adjective Phrase. Like drive slow and stay calm etc.

Thank you so much everybody here. All your comments are so enlightening to me!

From an ELU answer by me (it received two upvotes):
shot dead
English has a grammatical structure for describing the condition(s) that can occur to a person, animal or thing. It is a passive construction (subject + passive: be + adverb) where an adverb is appended after the action verb the subject has experienced or been subjected to. They all function like: He was shot dead. Here are some examples I've generated or recalled:
He was sprung loose.
He was eaten alive.
He was beaten silly.
She was carried high.
They were charmed fast.
The diamond was made fast. [secured to a ring, for example]
We are tickled pink. [my favourite]
They are punched out cold.
He is left cold.
The banner was hoisted aloft.
And that old favorite: He was scared shitless.
You are left speechless.
They were raised stupid.
It can be argued that what appears to be an adjective is actually an adverb because in the examples those qualifiers answer the question: HOW was X done to the subject? It's interesting to note that many of these are not situations one would want to find oneself in....ain't English great? :) I am struck dumb by it.

All these (excellent) examples involve someone being put into the state described by the adjective. The OP's examples seem wrong to me because they involve active verbs that should correctly be followed by an adverb - "Dress warmly" etc.
